# python list if statement

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a timetable generator based on the tide heightand I have the tide height in a list like below, each value represent the height of the tide at specific time e.g 9am=111 10am=123 etc..

`tide_list = [111, 123, 135, 143, 146, 140, 128, 113,  99]`

I want to display a message only if tide is above 100, eg in this case
9:00~16:00
is there any good way to do this other than setting up multiple if statements?

I tried putting the each value of the list into single variables but it looks too messy.

update:basically trying to simplify the following code

```
tide_list = [111, 123, 135, 143, 146, 140, 128, 113, 99]

time9,time10,time11,time12,time13,time14,time15,time16,time17=tide_list

if(time9>=100 and time10>=100 and time11>=100 and time12>=100 and 
time13>=100 and time14>=100 and time15>=100 and time16>=100 and 
time17>=100):
    print('9:00~17:00')
elif time9>=100 and time10>=100 and time11>=100 and time12>=100 and 
time13>=100 and time14>=100 and time15>=100 and time16>=100 and time17<100:
print('9:00~16:00')
elif time9>=100 and time10>=100 and time11>=100 and time12>=100 and 
time13>=100 
and time14>=100 and time15>=100 and time16<100 and time17<100:
print('9:00~15:00')
elif time9>=100 and time10>=100 and time11>=100 and time12>=100 and 
time13>=100 and time14>=100 and time15<100 and time16<100 and time17<100:
print('9:00~14:00')
etc...
```

Comment: What's the expected output if `tide_list=[111,0,111,0,111]` or something similar?

Comment: expected out put in that case would be an error message, as the tide should never fluctuate that much with in the timeframe I'm looking at

Comment: The code won't be less complicated than the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that the tide doesn't come several times in the given period.

```
# Sample data
tide_list = [111, 123, 135, 143, 146, 140, 128, 113, 99]

# Filter out the low values and replace the high values with their index in the list (plus an offset)
above = [i+9 for i, level in enumerate(tide_list) if level >= 100]

# You could replace this with the error logic of your choice
assert len(above) >= 1, 'The tide never came'

# Format and print the result
print('{0:02d}:00~{1:02d}:00'.format(above[0], above[-1]))
```

Comment: thank you so much SwiftsNamesake! this does exactly what I want it to do, and tested with several different test data and seems to work wonderfully for what i want

Comment: You're welcome. Clearly you're new to Python, so I hope you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a `for` loop and a single `if` statement:

```
tide_list = [111, 123, 135, 143, 146, 140, 128, 113, 99]

for height in tide_list:
    if height > 100:
        print(height)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! but I want to display a different message according to the tide, eg if the list was tide_list=[80,100,200,70] print('10am~11am')

Comment: @Jappyman If this answer isn't correct, you shouldn't accept it.

Answer (score -1):

thank you all of you who replied, 
I rethought my logic and I decided to do as below, which looks simpler than my first attempt.

```
tide_list = [111, 123, 135, 143, 146, 140, 128, 113, 99]

time9,time10,time11,time12,time13,time14,time15,time16,time17=tide_list

if time9>=100:
    start ='9:00~'
elif time10>=100:
    start ='10:00~'
elif time11>=100:
    start="11:00~"
elif time12>=100:
    start ='12:00~'
elif time13>=100:
    start="13:00~"
elif time14>=100:
    start ='14:00~'
elif time15>=100:
    start="15:00~"
elif time16>=100:
    start ='16:00~'
elif time17>=100:
    start="17:00~"
else:
    print("NO START TIME WAS SET!! CHECK DATA")
if time17>=100:
    end ='17:00'
elif time16>=100:
    end ='16:00'
elif time15>=100:
    end="15:00"
elif rime14>=100:
    start ='14:00'
elif time13>=100:
    end="13:00"
elif time12>=100:
    end ='12:00'
elif time11>=100:
    end="11:00"
elif time10>=100:
    end='10:00'
elif time19>=100:
    end="9:00"
else:
    print('NO END TIME SET CHECK DATA')
print start+end
```

Comment: So you basically want a time frame for when the tide is above a certain threshold? Furthermore, every entry in the list represents the water level at a whole hour, starting from 9 o'clock?